# Confirm SharePoint Web site in use or its deletion

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection

Easy question for earning easy point. SP 2013 on premise.

We had external consultants deploying a graphical solution. I have tested the function send email warning for deletion of unused sites and I am receiving some emails.

Content is 
Please follow the link below to your SharePoint Web site to confirm that it is still in use. 
https://ABCDEFG.com/_layouts/useconfirmation.aspx

If I click on the link I get an empty page, while I did remember the same happening in version 2010 and I had a page similar to this one

http://blogs.developpeur.org/blogs/fabrice69/image_INpfCA.png

Can someone confirm how the standard useconfirmation.aspx looks like in 2013 possibly with a screenshot? In case there is something wrong with the branding I can chase the agency to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get when I browse to the userconfirmation.aspx page in SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Comment: so you do not have to click anything?

Comment: Click on that (i) image will show this message